# Adding external .jar to debuggee classpath in netbeans 8

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an application whose main() uses ServiceLoader and reflection to produce a "report" of matching classes.  However, I'm unable to find a simple way to add an external .jar file to the classpath of a debugged program.  Prior to Netbeans 8, the answer was "Project->Libraries->Add Jar".  But that option no longer exists in Netbeans 8.  Tools->Libraries seems like it should be the same thing, but I can't see how to get from adding a library there, to making it available on the debuggee classpath.  The only thing I've seen is installing the .jar file into local maven repo, wrapping it in an artifact, and making it a project dependency.  But I don't want this to be a long-term change to the project itself, I just want to add a jar for a single debug session.

Answer (score 0):

I never did find an answer that involved only Netbeans settings.  There are ways to install maven jar-only artifacts into my local repo and reference them in the pom.xml, but that would have meant changing the project to change jars.  However, I did find a trick for augmenting the class path at runtime using reflection on the class loader, and this works.  Assume that args[i] contains the jar path to inject:

```
File file = new File(args[i]);
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
```